# Can I download csv file directly without defining a file path using csvhelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, csvhelper

I want to download the created CSV file without saving it in a predefined path. I'm using CSVHelper Library. (Website is not MVC based). Following is the code I'm using now.

```
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        using (var CHAIN = dt)
        {
            
            foreach (DataColumn column in CHAIN.Columns)
            {
                csv.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
            }
            csv.NextRecord();

          
            foreach (DataRow row in CHAIN.Rows)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < CHAIN.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(row[i]);
                }
                csv.NextRecord();
            }
        }
```

But I need to download the csv file directly into the browser without defining a path from StreamWriter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using CSVHelper to output stream to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093150/using-csvhelper-to-output-stream-to-browser)

Comment: Actually the website is not MVC based. Above question solved it for MVC based website

Comment: Please post the question with code snippet.

Comment: @DilipD I have added the code snippet

Comment: Good , Now its Clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `MemoryStream` this should be possible:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream)) {
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    using (var CHAIN = dt)
    {
    
        foreach (DataColumn column in CHAIN.Columns)
        {
            csv.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
        }
        csv.NextRecord();

  
        foreach (DataRow row in CHAIN.Rows)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < CHAIN.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                csv.WriteField(row[i]);
            }
            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
    writer.Flush();
}

memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var resultInBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
memoryStream.Close();
return resultInBytes;
```

You can return the `MemoryStream` as a response the following example is just an option, since I don't know what technology are you using so this webforms related code may help you:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/csv"; // or application/force-download
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;    filename=name_you_file.csv");
Response.BinaryWrite(resultInBytes);
Response.End();
```