# How do I create Csv in memory and return it to client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, csvhelper

How do I create a csv-file in memory and return it as `FileStreamResult`?
I tried to write to a `memorystream` and then return it with `FileStreamResult` but I always get the error `ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.`. I tried setting `leaveopen` to true  and disposing manually like told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666888/is-there-any-way-to-close-a-streamwriter-without-closing-its-basestream) but i still get the same error.

```
[HttpGet]
    public FileStreamResult GetData()
    {
        var myResult = DataGetter.GetData().ToList();
        using var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(memStream, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true);
        var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,true);
        csv.WriteRecords(myResult );
        var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(memStream, "text/csv");
        csv.Dispose();
        writer.Dispose();
        return fileStreamResult;
    }
```

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/prerequisites/streams/

Comment: `csv.Dispose();` you're here disposing it, so remove this line before returning it. Also, remember that streams implement ' IDisposable', so remember to enclose them in `using` blocks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using CSVHelper to output stream to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093150/using-csvhelper-to-output-stream-to-browser)

Comment: You need to write ROW of data with a Return at end of each row (WriteLine).  Then before adding new row Read a line from file to make room for a new row.  It is better to do with a List<List<string>> than a stream.

Comment: @gunr2171 it is working but i would like to reuse the same stream and not vonvert to bytearray and then open a new memorystream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like something is being disposed of too early.  I'd typically step through to see where the code gets to before the error is thrown.

Try removing the using from the "using var memStream" line(i've found c# 8.0 using statements sometimes don't quite work as expected) or wrapping it in a traditional using block.

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the stream's current position to the start with :

```
memStream.Position=0;
```

`FileStreamResul` will start reading from the stream's current position.

Answer (score -1):

When you dispose csv or writer they dispose base stream. Just don't dispose any stream. FileStreamResult will dispose baseStream when it sends it's data.

So remove these two lines of code.
csv.Dispose();
writer.Dispose();